# How to properly lex negative numbers?

Tags: java, lexer

Following [this example](http://giocc.com/writing-a-lexer-in-java-1-7-using-regex-named-capturing-groups.html) for implementing a simple lexer, I found that it doesn't properly resolve the operators.
E.g. if you give it a string `1 - 2` it works, but `1-2` does not.
Second example gives two tokens: `1` and `-2`, but it should recognize the minus sign.
It fails because the regex `NUMBER("-?[0-9]+")` succeeds first.

If I switch the regexes, then it fails on `1+-2` (4 tokens instead of 3).

Can this problem be solved with this "just-a-list-of-regexes" approach somehow?
Or we need to look ahead and resolve it manually always? How would that look like?

Comment: You can split the input by "-" and amend the incoming input as per expected input for the regex you have. not only this way you can also check if "-" contains a string.

Comment: You don't. You lex the operators and the numeric literals separately, and let the expression parser sort it out. Only the parser has enough context to do that. Your source suffers from the delusion that all operators are binary operators. And it contains several other misconceptions as well. A real lexer for expressions is a lot simpler than this. Find a better resoource.

Comment: @user207421 thanks for explaining, that makes more sense. :)